# How to print the values from the multiples of methods

Tags: java, methods, printing, return-value

I've been trying to print the value I've obtained from another method into another void method by using the main method...yeah I know, it's very complicated to explain, so I'll show how it looks like below:

```
public class MultMethods{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        anotherMethod();
        printMethod();
    }
    public static String anotherMethod(){
        return value;
    }

    public static void printMethod(){
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
public class MultMethods{
public static void main(String[] args){
    String str = anotherMethod();
    printMethod(str);
}
public static String anotherMethod(){
    String value = "ABC";
    return value;
}

public static void printMethod(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to achieve something like

```
public class MultMethods{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        printMethod(anotherMethod());
    }
    public static String anotherMethod(){
        return value;
    }

    public static void printMethod(String value){
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Getting a string value and passing this to another method. When you are doing this, won't it be easy to write:

```
public class MultMethods{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(anotherMethod());
    }
    public static String anotherMethod(){
        return value;
    }
}
```